# error in applying cv::Pow

Tags: c++, opencv

i am selva. I am trying to apply pow value of 2.0 for an image in my project. 
I am able to apply pow using the following method.

```
`cv::Mat src = imread("123.png",0);
 cv::Mat dest ( src.size(), CV_8UC1);
 for( int i=0; i<src.rows; i++)
   for(int j=0; j<src.cols; j++)
     dest.at<uchar>(i,j) = (int) (255* std::pow(src.at<uchar>(i,j)/255.0,val))`
```

But this increases the execution time. 
I am trying to implement pow transformation(GAMMA) by,

`Mat src = imread("123.png",0); 
     cv::Mat dest(src.size(),CV_8UC1);
     src.convertTo(src,CV_32FC1);
     cv::pow(src,2.0,dest);`

I am getting a complete white image. I don't know what to change in my code to get the right output. Help me to solve this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have converted it from Unsigned Char (UC) to 32-bit floating point. You have converted your source, but not the destination type. Something is getting lost here.

Your `pow` type, convert it to `CV_32FC1` and try again. Also, check for your scaling factors that is necessary for convertTo method. It's in OpenCV documentation - http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html

Someone has already explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837876/opencv-convertto-returns-white-image-sometimes)

Comment: It shows error. You wanted to check with CV_32FC1 or CV_32C1??

Comment: I have also tried with CV_32FC1, bu the error is same.

Comment: I have changed my dest type to CV_32FC1. could i convert it to Unsigned Char again??

Comment: Check the updated answer and try from the beginning.

Comment: I have changed my code like this and it works,                `Mat src = imread("123.bmp",0); 
cv::Mat dest(src.size(),CV_32FC1);
src.convertTo(src,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0); 
cv::pow(src,2.0,dest);
dest.convertTo(dest,CV_8UC1,255);`                                  And Thanks for your time.

Comment: @SELVA           No problem, remember you can also put a question up on OpenCV forum for different explanations and solutions.